# AS3: Working with multiple sounds & channels - are there any good libraries for this?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, open-source, soundchannel

Are there any audio management libraries for ActionScript 3? The more tailored they are for game development the better.

I'm finding it hard to understand and work with multiple channels, which is making a lot of my audio sound screwy and cancel each other out, etc. I've been working on an RPG that can at a given time have quite a number of sounds playing such as environmental noise (like opening doors, thunder, rain, etc), walking enemies, inventory sounds (for events like dropping an item into your inventory), passive spell-casting sounds, voice clips, weapon swinging etc.

Alternatively, if there are any good resources that explain how to use multiple sound channels strategically or if someone can give a nice overview in an answer, that would be fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about strategic use of sounds, I just play them willy nilly as I have to.  But there is an interesting sound library called [StandingWave3](https://github.com/maxl0rd/standingwave3). This is probably overkill, as it is mostly for sound generation than simply playing sounds.

Two popular Flash game frameworks ([Flashpunk](http://flashpunk.net) and [Flixel](http://flixel.org)) both have a couple classes for managing sounds.  This is more game specific, but I'm not sure if you can directly use the classes in your game without importing the whole framework.  Of course, these are open source projects, so you could check the source for ideas.

- API for Flixel Sound http://flixel.org/docs/org/flixel/FlxSound.html
- API for Flashpunk sfx http://flashpunk.net/docs/net/flashpunk/Sfx.html

Edit: Here's another game lib with a sound/sfx component: http://code.google.com/p/popforge/

Comment: On a semi-related note, there is a spectacular project on gitHub that provides some very useful code for top-down RPGs.  It is a companion library for the Flashpunk framework: https://github.com/dolgion1/FlashPunk-JRPG-Engine

Comment: Nice framework. Sadly I've already developed my own top view RPG framework that I'm using at the moment - it's just missing something nice for the audio control :P I'll have a play with a couple of your suggestions and see how I go :)

Comment: I managed to have a look at the sound management in these frameworks and work out how to approach my own implementation. Thanks!